# jQuery get Geolocation of Device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geocode

Is there a way to use javascript, jquery, or any basic modern API to get the geolocation of a user via a typical web app?

Typically I'm looking to see if devices have a standard way of making the current geographical position known, and if it's excessible through most device's browsers, and if there is a standard way of accessing it.

Comment: Yes, there is [a standard Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/). MDN's "[Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation)" can help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

This should give you a starting point.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data){console.log(data)})
```

Comment: You totally rock. Thanks a lot.